# Show that $(A\wedge B’) \vee B ≡ A \vee B$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

How do I prove this using laws of logical equivalency?
$$
(A\wedge B’) \vee B ≡ A \vee B
$$
**What I tried**. $(A \vee B') \wedge (A \vee A)$ I started by applying the distributive laws. Is this the right path?

Comment: Distributive law is the proof, plus $q \vee q' \equiv V$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$%
\require{begingroup}
\begingroup
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\Ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\then}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\when}{\leftarrow}
\newcommand{\fa}[2]{\forall #1 \left( #2 \right) }
\newcommand{\ex}[2]{\exists #1 \left( #2 \right) }
\newcommand{\exun}[2]{\exists ! #1 \left( #2 \right) }
\newcommand{\F}{\mathcal F}
\newcommand{\equiv}{\leftrightarrow}
%$

$$\calc
    (A\land B') \lor B
\op\equiv\hint{distributive law}
    (A\lor B)\land(B'\lor B)
\op\equiv\hint{tautology}
    (A\lor B)\land \text{tautology}
\op\equiv\hint{tautology law}
    A\lor B
\endcalc$$